# SSH connection to jupyter notebook opens but browser unable to connect

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-server

I have a bizarre problem with my SSH connection. I am trying to connect to Ubuntu server from Windows client (local network, Bitvise SSH client).

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8885
```

Everything launches as normal. I then go to my client

```
ssh -p 2222 -N -f -L 8800:localhost:8885 user@server
```

Everything seems normal and I get in. I then go my browser and try localhost:8800 and localhost:8885. Neither responds. Any tips would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: When you run ssh with -L 8800:localhost:8885 and then try to connect with your browser, what exactly happens? What does your browser display? Is your browser configured to use a proxy?

Comment: @Kenster Chrome gives me "This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect." and Firefox says "Unable to connect. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8800." There is no proxy configuration

Comment: Also, I have generated config file and allowed NotebookApp.Allow_origin and NotebookApp.Allow_IP to all addresses. Still no access via browser

Comment: SSH may be failing to set up the port forward for some reason. (1) run `netstat -an | grep 8800` to see if anything is actually listening on port 8800. (2) Run ssh with the `-vvv` parameter to get debugging information that would include port forwarding messages. (3) Try running ssh with the `ExitOnForwardFailure` to make it complain if it can't set up forwarding.

Comment: @Kenster many thanks. I'll give that a try when back at my desk.

Comment: @Kenster I tried all of the above and nothing out of the usual came up. Bizarre.

Comment: Try this: while the ssh connection with its port forward is running, run "telnet localhost 8800". If it connects and doesn't immediately disconnect, type "GET /" and hit return twice.

Comment: Thanks @Kenster. I get telnet localhost 8800
    Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused.

Comment: Correction, I get telnet localhost 8800
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GEt/

Connection closed by foreign host.

Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: That suggests that the remote ssh server is failing to connect to jupyter to complete the tunnel, or else jupyter is dropping the connection for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @Kenster. I can open Jupyter locally on the server via Links, just not from the client. I have also tried disabling all existing firewalls (client, server, and even router). Completely puzzled.

Comment: It's working! I am not sure what solved it, but thanks so much for all the input.

Comment: I tried to connect again this morning and the connection failed.  I suddenly realised that I had used wi-fi with my laptop for the last hour last night when I finally succeeded in connecting. I pulled the ethernet cable out and, lo and behold, I succeeded in connecting. This is a little weird. My server is cabled to the router which also handles wi-fi (i.e. there is only one router). How can the same router refuse cabled connection from my laptop but accept wi-fi? I also have a switch where I connect my laptop and server which then goes to the router. Could that be the culprit?